# Error HRESULT E_FAIL when iterating through for loop only

Tags: vb.net

I'm seeing the good old "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException HResult=0x80004005 Message=Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component" error when attempting to find an item via a for loop as shown below:

```
For i = 1 to itemList.Count
    oObject = itemList.Item(i)
Next
```

But not if I hardcode the index, this finds item 1 without issue:

`oObject = itemList.Item(1)`

Obviously I don't want to do that and need to search through all the objects in my "itemList" to find the one I'm looking for.

I'm being intentionally vague because the software I'm working in is Dassault 3D Experience but am writing macros for it through Visual Studio 2017. I'm not sure where to even start debugging this sort of issue so any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Edit: adding full code of what I'm trying to do here (find an object, display its name, also select it on screen to double check.  I will later add a check to make sure the object found in each loop is really what I'm looking for).  All variables have been declared before this section.

```
selactive = CATIA.ActiveEditor.Selection
selactive.Clear()

product1Service = CATIA.ActiveEditor.GetService("PLMProductService")
oRootOcc = product1Service.RootOccurrence
cVPMOccurrences = oRootOcc.Occurrences

For i = 1 to cVPMOccurrences.Count
      oVPMOccurrence = cVPMOccurrences.Item(i)
      selactive.Add(oVPMOccurrence)
      MsgBox(oVPMOccurrence.Name)
Next
```

The line that fails is `oVPMOccurrence = cVPMOccurrences.Item(i)`

Comment: being intentionally vague doesn't really help us help you.  Can you perhaps change you For loop to a For Each?  What exactly is the itemList? And what is the items collection loaded with?

Comment: I will edit my original post to include the full code of what I'm trying to do.

Thank you for the suggestion of "for each," but that also does not work properly here.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like this with a For Each loop?

```
For each oVPMOccurrence as oRootOcc.Occurrence in cVPMOccurrences.Items
      selactive.Add(oVPMOccurrence)
      MsgBox(oVPMOccurrence.Name)
Next
```

Using a For Each means you don't have to worry at all about the index

Not sure what the type of oVPMOccurrence is as you haven't specified

Comment: Thanks for the help.  A "for each" loop works as you've described for this case.  I'm still not sure why a regular for loop throws an error, there must be another issue somewhere in my code or my system configuration.  I'll use the "for each" loops moving forward.

Comment: Yup, generally using for each loo pattern when iterating collections is the easier way to go

Answer (score 0):

Most indexes in .net are zero base. I don't know what `itemList` is but I suspect the index of the first item is 0.

```
For i = 0 to itemList.Count - 1
    oObject = itemList.Item(i)
Next
```

Not sure why you want to overwrite the value of `oObject` on every iteration.

Comment: I edited my question above to add the actual code I'm using.  For whatever reason cVPMOccurrences starts at index 1, but either way, the starting index should be found in the array.  I know for sure there are 6 items in my array.